# Why Task<bool> is faster then Task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

I have function which archives files, so I tried to create async version of it. 
But for some reason if I change return type of the function from **Task** to **Task < bool >** it works much faster.

Below is two versions of the implementation.

```
public Task<bool> PsiZipFilesAsync(string zipFileName_, string[] listOfFiles_)
    {

        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive())
            {
                //zip.Password = pass;
                zip.EncryptionType = EncryptionType.PkZip;
                zip.AddFiles(listOfFiles_);

                zip.Save(zipFileName_);

            }
        });

        return Task.FromResult(true);

    }
    public Task PsiZipFilesAsync2(string zipFileName_, string[] listOfFiles_)
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive())
            {
                //zip.Password = pass;
                zip.EncryptionType = EncryptionType.PkZip;
                zip.AddFiles(listOfFiles_);

                zip.Save(zipFileName_);

            }
        });



    }
```

And I call them as

```
try
            {
                await zip.PsiZipFilesAsync("async_archive.zip", ofd.FileNames);
                //await zip.PsiZipFilesAsync2("async_archive.zip", ofd.FileNames);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception!");

            }
```

Time is greatly different for the same files to be zipped.

00:00:00.0049702 - Task < bool > version

00:00:08.4380303 - Task version

Does anyone come across same issue? Why would this make such a big difference?

One issue is that in **Task < bool >** version I can't catch exception.

Comment: How were you calculating those performance numbers?  I don't see any such code in your sample and it is almost certainly the case that the reason you are seeing a difference is that you are not writing the correct timing code.

Comment: I am using Stopwatch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in the first example you are not actually awaiting the work item, you are starting the work task in the background, but then return `Task.FromResult(true)` and await on that which sets the task result to true and returns instantly, whereas in the second example you are actually performing work and awaiting the completion.

Change the first sample to look like the below and try again:

```
public Task<bool> PsiZipFilesAsync(string zipFileName_, string[] listOfFiles_)
    {

        return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive())
            {
                //zip.Password = pass;
                zip.EncryptionType = EncryptionType.PkZip;
                zip.AddFiles(listOfFiles_);

                zip.Save(zipFileName_);

            }
            return true;
        });

    }
```